# Send Authorization cookie when calling OData service

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have 2 web applications.
The first web application contains ASP.NET web pages and used a Membership provider for authentication.
The second web application is strictly an OData WEB API site that requires authentication.

Both sites have the same "machineKey validationKey / decryptionKey" in the web config and both are using "Forms" authentication with the same "forms name of .TESTAUTH"

When I call the OData service and inspect the IDentity for both the thread and httpcontext they are both empty for the name and isauthenticated.

So how do I get the OData to recognize the .TESTAUTH cookie?

EDIT:
Well here is what I did. It doesn't seem right but if someone knows a better way please let me know.

```
dbContext.BuildingRequest += AddCookie;
private void AddCookie(object sender, Microsoft.OData.Client.BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
{       
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(".TESTAUTH");

    e.Headers.Add("Cookie", ".TESTAUTH=" + authCookie.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did to solve the problem.

```
dbContext.BuildingRequest += AddCookie;
private void AddCookie(object sender, Microsoft.OData.Client.BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
{       
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(".TESTAUTH");

    e.Headers.Add("Cookie", ".TESTAUTH=" + authCookie.Value);
}
```