# How to access protected OData resources from c# application using Microsofts OData v4 Client T4 Code Generator

Tags: cookies, odata, t4

I have a website which exposes an ODatas $metadata but to do anything further requires the request to be authenticated (using a cookie).

I want to access this from a console app, not a browser.

I am using [Microsofts Odata V4 client code generator.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bingl.ODatav4ClientCodeGenerator)

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a wrapper around the provided `Container` created by the OData client code generator.

2) Log in and get the cookie you need for authentication

3) Add a hook to the request builder, so you can apply cookies at request time. For my app, I specifically needed the cookie with the name `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`

Here is a full working example. You can instantiate this container with the user and password needed as defined at the bottom. This MUST match whatever the controller at the Login API is expecting.

```
using Nito.AsyncEx;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyAppOdataOdataService.Default
{
    public class MyAppOdataContainer : Container
    {
        public Cookie[] _MyAppOdataAuthcookie;
        public string cookieAuthName = ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie";
        private string baseurl = "https://TheAppwWebsite.co.jp/";
        public MyAppOdataContainer(MyAppOdataLoginInfo logininfo ) :
            base(new Uri("https://TheAppwWebsite.co.jp/odata/"))
        {

            // init authorization
            _MyAppOdataAuthcookie = AsyncContext.Run(() => AuthenticateUser(logininfo));

            if (_MyAppOdataAuthcookie == null) throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();


            this.BuildingRequest += AddCookie;

        }

        private void AddCookie(object sender, Microsoft.OData.Client.BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieAuthName+"=" + _MyAppOdataAuthcookie.First(c=>c.Name == cookieAuthName).Value);
        }


        private async Task<Cookie[]> AuthenticateUser(MyAppOdataLoginInfo logininfo)
        {
            CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.CookieContainer = cookies;
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseurl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Uri uri = new Uri(baseurl + "/Login/Login");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, logininfo);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Return the URI of the created resource.
            return  cookies.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>().ToArray();


        }


    }

    public class MyAppOdataLoginInfo
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Thanks:

[How to apply the cookie:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943478/send-authorization-cookie-when-calling-odata-service)

[Creating the client code:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-client-app)

[CookieContainer explaination:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx)

[Post operation idea here - for authorizing - having to use PostAsJsonAsync](https://dzone.com/articles/web-api-with-httpclient-or-consume-web-api-from-co)